# Stereotype in sequence diagram visio 2013

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram, visio2013

I would like to display stereotype(Boundary, Control, Entity) in my sequence diagram using visio 2013 like from this [link](http://www.tracemodeler.com/articles/a_quick_introduction_to_uml_sequence_diagrams/images/object%20stereotypes%20with%20icons.png)

Howefer, i can't find a suitable way to make this in Visio 2013/

Is there any way to make stereotype like what i want in Microsoft Visio 2013? Any Ideas?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: at Jef ..., mean, @CodingHorror: This is a specific software question. Questions like this, are sometimes answered, in this forum, but, its better for ask at the software manufacturer forum.

Comment: ... and, in U.M.L., when the developer uses icons instead of class / object boxes, stereotypes are not mean to be used. Maybe your software does not support it, either. By the way, using notes, its fine.

Comment: The short answer is that Visio 2013 does not support rigorous UML modeling anymore. See this article: https://blogs.office.com/2012/10/17/uml-and-database-diagrams-in-the-new-visio/